A pop-up dialog screen that should persist even after phone restarted
When user hits a button on app screen it triggers an alarm sound with a dialog box saying you turned on alarm... to turn this off user should enter a password. Some users removes the battery or restart phone to skip entering the password. So I need this dialog to persist and users shouldn't move forward in the app without entering the password. An alarm API is connected to backend. if user don't enter the password the backend saves the state as "alarm ringing" forever.
I am thinking about creating a file inside phones internal storage, lets call that file name as alarmmanager.txt and keep the dialog state stored inside that file to access after the phone restarted or even after app data cleared.
Is there any better way to do this?

Please explain your use case in more detail. It's unclear (to me at least) what "a dialog screen that popped up when the alarm was turned on" means. If you can clearly articulate your requirements, it'll be easier to suggest a solution.

Use case is this: When user hits alarm button, the alarm turn on with a dialog box saying you turned on alarm... to turn this off enter password. Some users removes the battery or restart to skip this. So I need this dialog to persist and users shouldn't move forward in the app without entering the password. This alarm is actually connected to backend. if user don't enter the password the backend saves the state as "alarm ringing" forever.

Friend - no one but you knows what "hits alarm button" means. Please edit your question (don't post a comment) that better explains what you're trying to do. What is "alarm button"? Is that a button in your app? What "alarm" turns on? Are you talking about setting an alarm with AlarmManager? An alarm clock? What?

What a strange feature. In any case, if this is connected to a backend, why don't you get the current state from the backend to determine if you should show the dialog again? Or use SharedPreferences and just save a bool "isAlarmRinging"?

I'm no app developer, but since you are keeping the TXT file in internal storage so only your app can access it, you should be all right. However, I would keep an encryption key rather than a TXT file. Also, you'd need to ensure that your app creates the key/file after the first launch and will only proceed to next activity only if the key/file is present, this will prevent the bypassing by simply clearing app data.
My draft workflow will be as follows - after the first launch, create an encryption key>store the password using sha256>encrypt the password and store it>if the encryption key is missing (data cleared), prompt the user to create a new password.

Your question is not clear. Please ask questions clearly and in a readable way. It would be great for your benefit.

I didn't ask any question mate
